# How to adjust CSS animation to prevent opacity overlap?

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to build an animation using CSS that represents the movement of a certain `<div>`.

To represent that movement, I'd like to my `<div>` to leave a fading trail behind.

I accomplished that effect, but I'm not totally satisfied, because the opacity of each `<div>` (that creates my desired movement representation) overlap with one another, turning specific parts of the animation with more opacity that it should have.

My exact code that reproduces this unwanted effect is the fiddle below:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zLpvfek/1/)

Could someone please explain to me how to prevent my animation from doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you want ?

I wrapped all your divs in one container and only animate that container.

Also gave left property to each div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 16.5px;
  height:80px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  animation-timing-function:linear;
}

.container {
  width: 0px;
  animation: newmove 2.4s infinite;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#div1 {background-color: red; left: 148.5px}
#div2 {background-color: red; opacity: 0.9; left: 132px}
#div3 {background-color: red; opacity: 0.8; left: 115.5px}
#div4 {background-color: red; opacity: 0.7; left: 99px}
#div5 {background-color: red; opacity: 0.6; left: 82.5px}
#div6 {background-color: red; opacity: 0.5; left: 66px}
#div7 {background-color: red; opacity: 0.4; left: 49.5px}
#div8 {background-color: red; opacity: 0.3; left: 33px;}
#div9 {background-color: red; opacity: 0.2; left: 16.5px}
#div10 {background-color: red; opacity: 0.1; left: 0px}

@keyframes newmove {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 165px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: yellow">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div4"></div>
    <div id="div5"></div>
    <div id="div6"></div>
    <div id="div7"></div>
    <div id="div8"></div>
    <div id="div9"></div>
    <div id="div10"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your example didn't achieved my desired effect, but lead me to it. I wanted to the main object to move through the path. So I did this https://jsfiddle.net/4ctbo2v0/

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but sadly my specific application can't apply this solution... The div isn't a rectangle, but is inclined to the right. So, when the div increases it's width, it don't completely shows the faded path...